# logstash kv filter cannot convert strings to integers

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a log with a format similar to:

```
stage_name=stage1
stage_duration=30
stage_result=failed
```

The problem is I am using this parser on multiple log files with each basically containing numerous kv pairs.

Is there a way to recognize when values are integers and cast them as such without having to use mutate on every single key value pair? (Rather than a string)

i found that using ruby will might solve my issue by i need to understand how to replace the ' ' = space with /n = next row

```
input {
    stdin {}
}

filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
            fieldArray = event['message'].split(' ');
            for field in fieldArray
                name = field.split('=')[0];
                value = field.split('=')[1];
                if value =~ /\A\d+\Z/
                    event[name] = value.to_i
                else
                    event[name] = value
                end
            end
        "
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mapping is not given when a field is created, the field type is automatically determined using ECS (Elastic Common Schema).
The same goes for the Logstash kv filter [Ref.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html#plugins-filters-kv-ecs_metadata)

You can use dynamic template to determine the type of the field.

*For example: If a field name is **stage_duration** or ***_duration**, let them be integers.*

To set the dynamic template: [Ref.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#dynamic-mapping-runtime-fields)

```
PUT hagay_bar/
{
   "mapping": {
     "dynamic_templates": [
       {
         "strings_as_integer": {
           "match_mapping_type": "string",
           "match": "*_duration",
           "mapping": {
           "type": "integer"
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

**Note: The mapping of an index cannot be changed. A new index must be created.**

Comment: can you please review my edit and see if this method will also work? im looking for a way to parse it from the logstash side. i only need to figure out how to replace the space with "next line"

Comment: at the end i solved it statically ```input {
    file {
        mode => "read"
        file_completed_action => "delete"
        start_position => "beginning"
        path => "/data/elastic/*.log"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        exit_after_read => true
    }
}
filter {
    kv {
    }
    mutate {
        convert => {"BUILD_ID" => "integer"}
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["10.56.10.152:9200"]
        index => "jenkins"
    }
}```